# VB.net: Remove ToolStripPanel/ToolStripContentPanel

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, toolstrippanel

While working on a project VB.net project in Visual Studio 2013 Community, i accidently inserted the ToolStripPanel/ToolStripContentPanel controls combination.

Unfortunately however, I now cannot delete it. Can anyone advise as to how to go about doing this? There must surely be a way. Unfortunately, I cant just hit Undo either as the project has been saved since.

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't a question for stackoverflow, everything on here has to be about coding in a way. I'm not that experienced when it comes to the stackexchange community though so I could be wrong. The ToolStripPanel is supposed to show up next to your timers at the bottom of your screen by default. (http://i.gyazo.com/a43bb49ca0f4439ece367d1ac9ca720b.png)

Comment: When you say you cannot delete it, why can't you delete it?  What happens when you try?  Have you tried deleting it in the designer.vb code?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the MenuStrip (Default name MenuStrip1) to another form in your project. Go back to the problem form. Right-click the ToolStripPanel, click Select, and then hit delete. This will delete everything. Copy MenuStrip1 back to the problem form, and your original menu should show up. You may have to add the 'Handles' clause back in to any menu events. For example, if you have an event procedure named 'MnuFileOpen_Click' you may have to reinsert 'Handles mnuFileOpen.Click.